# Heroku App Missing HTML Module?

Tags: javascript, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app on Heroku using Dropbox Sync, but it says internal server error, and the logs show this:

```
2016-08-04T16:39:11.536583+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-08-04T16:39:11.536571+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'html'
2016-08-04T16:39:11.533835+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=comboracle.herokuapp.com request_id=3d60846c-2426-4a6f-a7a9-dbf89e5786b5 fwd="174.67.241.64" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=79ms status=500 bytes=232
```

My index.js file is set up as such:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('public/handcheck.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('The app is live on port' + app.get('port'));
});
```

And my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "combo-oracle",
  "description": "combo probability evaluator for tcgs",
  "repository": "https://github.com/heroku/comboracle",
  "keywords": ["node", "express", "static"],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*"
  }
}
```

As I understand it, html shouldn't require any specific modules to work. My local testing showed that rendering .html files worked, but I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `response.render` without having a view engine defined. If you want to use the `render` method, you *need* to use a view engine like [ejs](http://www.embeddedjs.com/).

If you just want to render a static HTML file, you can do so like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');

var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.render('public/handcheck.html');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('The app is live on port' + app.get('port'));
});
```